# React Native How to pass textinput values from child component to parent component

Tags: react-native, react-props, textinput

I want to make a simple textinput operation. User can input its name.

I created class based parent (App.js) and functional based (InputName.js)

I called child component in parent class as

```
<InputName />
```

I created InputName.js as

```
 const InputName = () => {

const [text, setText] = React.useState(null);
return ( <TextInput 
autoCapitalize='none' 
onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)} 
style={styles.userTextInput} />)
```

}

My question is How can I reach onChangeText value in child component from parent.

```
   //imports
   import EmailInput from '../components/EmailInput';
   

   class Login extends Component { 

        state = {
        inputValue: '',
    }
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onChangeText = (text) => {
    this.setState({inputValue: text.target.value});
    };

    render() {
 return (
  <EmailInput value={this.state.inputValue} onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text)} />  )}};
```

// Input File

```
    const EmailInput = (onChangeText, value) => {
    const [text, setText] = React.useState(null);
    return ( <TextInput 
    autoCapitalize='none'
    value={value} 
    onChangeText={onChangeText} 
    style={//styles} />)
  }
```

Comment: your question is confusing? can you please elaborate more with additional code snippet?

Comment: I edited. I hope it defines clearly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass your method from child component in parent class. here is an working example:

```
import React from 'react';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';

class EmailInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const {onTextChange, inputValue} = this.props;
    return (
      <TextInput
        autoCapitalize="none"
        value={inputValue}
        onChangeText={onTextChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default EmailInput;
```

in your main class just do the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import EmailInput from '../components/EmailInput';

class LandingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      locals: {},
      inputValue: '',
    };
  }

  onTextChange = text => {
    this.setState({inputValue: text.target.value});
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
             <EmailInput
          inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
          onChangeText={text => this.onTextChange(text)}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const apiLoading = state.common.apiLoading;
  return {
    apiLoading,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(LandingScreen);
```

Comment: It should be <InputName value= {this.state.inputValue} right? I tried your codes When I type it gives props.onChangeText is not a function.

Comment: @nogabemist sorry my bad. i forgot that while typing the answer. i have updated the answer and have you created onTextChange in your main view?

Comment: onChangeText = (text) => {this.setState({inputValue: text});};   I have this in main.

Comment: @nogabemist it have to work. this is the way to do this. can you add your full code of main screen and component. ill debug and let u know.

Comment: @nogabemist i have updated the working answer. try it now